# Should we use jQuery custom selector, they are working correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-selectors

I have created simple code

`$.expr[':'].test = function(node,index){
    console.log(node,index)
}`

and executed them

```
$('div:test()')
```

All index was 0 and I don't now why? 
Should use them or not ? 
I don't want use additional [libraries](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle)

Answer (score 0):

I think its supposed to be $('div:test'). When I tried it in the browser I got a variety of indices. It seems to work

[image: example]

Comment: Also, sizzle is a core part of jQuery and $.expr actually is a [function](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/dist/sizzle.js) (starting at line 994) in Sizzle